# Changing the direction of the gravity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

In my game, normally the player goes up while the space bar is pressed and fall if space bar is not pressed. My aim is: when the player collides with a specific object, the gravity should be work in an opposite way and when we press the space bar , the player should go down (for 10 seconds). Here is my code to move the player upwards:

```
  public void Update(){
    Vector2 vel=rb.velocity;
    float ang = Mathf.Atan2(vel.y,10)*Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,0,ang));
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)){
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up*gravity*Time.deltaTime*2000f);
}
```

Comment: After 10 seconds the controls should work normally

Comment: Should be a simple case of `-gravity`, no?

Comment: Ok then how can I make the movement to work opposite

Comment: Also how can I make it last for 10 seconds

Comment: If you have further questions either alter your question or ask a new one, that's not really what comments are for

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too much about how your code is structured, perhaps I can suggest something like this:

```
public class GameEngine
{
    private double gravity = 9.81;

    private void GravityFlip_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InvertGravity();
        Task.Run(() => InvertGravity(10));
    }

    private void InvertGravity(int delaySeconds = 0)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(delaySeconds * 1000);
        gravity = 0 - gravity;
    }
}
```

When the "player collides with a specific object", invoke the `GravityFlip_Event`. This will first "flip gravity" with immediate event and then invoke a task with a delay of the required length; flipping it back there after.

A better approach may be to create an "effects" class that can modify the environment in any other way you might like, perhaps base around a `System.Timers.Timer`.

Comment: what is object sender and e ?

Comment: They are standard event arguments: The `sender`, the `object` that raised the event, and `e` is the `EventArgs`, being additional information about the event.  Depending on your code they don't have to be there. You didn't provide much information.

Comment: @Iyona Did this work for you? If Yes, please mark the question as answered.